# Image of $(A-AB)$ and Image of $(B-AB)$ have trivial intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\Bbb R^n$ denote the $n$-dimensional real vector space. Let $A, B$ be two linear transformations on $\Bbb R^n$ such that $A\circ A = A$ and $B\circ B = B$, where $\circ$ denotes composition of linear transformations. Show that
> the ranges of $A − A\circ B$ and $B − A \circ B$ have only the zero vector in common.

I have proved that null space of $B$ is equal to the image of $(I-B)$ and null space of $A$ is equal to the image of $(I-A)$ from the given conditions. Any hints from here will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at $A(B-AB) $ and $A(A-AB)$

Comment: Ah got it. So the image of (B-AB) is contained in null A and image of (A-AB) is contained in the image of A. And we can prove that null A and Image A are disjoint. Right? If there is a more elegant or natural way do let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: More generally, for any projection matrix $A$ and any matrices $B,C$ (with compatible sizes),$${\rm im}(A\circ C)\cap {\rm im}((I-A)\circ B)\subset {\rm im}(A)\cap {\rm im}(I-A)=\{0\}.$$